# Why are Caliburn.Micro zombie views sticking around?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, caliburn.micro

We have an application written with Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1. There is a login ViewModel (`LoginViewModel`) on our application. The associated `LoginView` appears to the user at startup and after logging out.

The ViewModel has a notifying boolean property bound to dependency property on a UI control in the `LoginView`, which in turn sends off an event (using `Message.Attach`).

We suddenly realized that if the user logs in and out a number of times, the number of times the code hits the dependency property callback increases. So, the second time you log in you hit the callback twice, then three times after three logins, and so on. Eventually you see it dip down again. Some pattern like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, etc. would be an example.

Presumably there is garbage collection going on which explains why the numbers drop after a few iterations. However, we're concerned we're doing something wrong (or maybe there's a bug in Caliburn.Micro?).

We checked Caliburn.Micro's view cache and there is never more than one instance of `LoginView` there.

While we understand Caliburn.Micro may be regenerating views each time the `LoginViewModel` activates, we were assuming that the DataContext would be nulled out on the old instance of the view. That appears to not be happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using any sort of Container? Autofac, SimpleContainer, MEF?

Comment: Yes, Autofac and the LoginViewModel is injected into the parent ViewModel initially.

Comment: I would wager a guess its a registration with the container thing.  What do you have the scope of the viewmodel registered as?

Comment: @mvermef Both the `LoginViewModel` (and its parent) are registered as `builder.RegisterType<LoginViewModel>().AsSelf();` The LoginViewModel is only ever constructed once.